# How to change color of checkbox material table ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am using Material table in my project and want to change color of checkbox on selection[image]. How to do that??

```
function BasicSelection() {
  return (
    <MaterialTable
      title="Basic Selection Preview"
      columns={[
        { title: 'Name', field: 'name' },
        { title: 'Surname', field: 'surname' },
        { title: 'Birth Year', field: 'birthYear', type: 'numeric' },
        {
          title: 'Birth Place',
          field: 'birthCity',
          lookup: { 34: 'İstanbul', 63: 'Şanlıurfa' },
        },
      ]}
      data={[
        { name: 'Mehmet', surname: 'Baran', birthYear: 1987, birthCity: 63 },
        { name: 'Zerya Betül', surname: 'Baran', birthYear: 2017, birthCity: 34 },
      ]}        
      options={{
        selection: true
      }}
    />
  )
}
```

Comment: did you check this https://material-ui.com/components/checkboxes/#checkbox-with-formcontrollabel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think if you want to change that color, chances are high you are using that color else where in your components. Probably think about theming the table to match the app look. Material Table provides a theming snipped that you can use to override the default `secondary.main` color applied to the checkbox.

[Styling with MuiThemeProvider Example](https://material-table.com/#/docs/features/styling)

```
function StylingWithMuiThemeProvider() {
  const theme = createMuiTheme({
    palette: {
      primary: {
        main: '#4caf50',
      },
      secondary: {
        main: '#ff0000',
      },
    },

  });

  return (
    <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>

    <MaterialTable
      title="Basic Selection Preview"
      columns={[
        { title: 'Name', field: 'name' },
        { title: 'Surname', field: 'surname' },
        { title: 'Birth Year', field: 'birthYear', type: 'numeric' },
        {
          title: 'Birth Place',
          field: 'birthCity',
          lookup: { 34: 'İstanbul', 63: 'Şanlıurfa' },
        },
      ]}
      data={[
        { name: 'Mehmet', surname: 'Baran', birthYear: 1987, birthCity: 63 },
        { name: 'Zerya Betül', surname: 'Baran', birthYear: 2017, birthCity: 34 },
      ]}        
      options={{
        selection: true
      }}
    />
    </MuiThemeProvider>
  )
}
```